# Bootstrap. Advice needed re local CSS file and CDN link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I am very new and green so please forgive the basic question.
 When I create a site using Bootstrap I believe that I include the link to the Bootstrap CDN file in the head section of each page and I also include a link to my own CSS style sheet. Is that correct? Or can I put the cdn file links in my style sheet and then just put a link to the style sheet in the HTML head section of every page?

Same question re JavaScript. Do I link to the cdn file on every page of my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to include the js and css cdn links in every page or u can download these and add it to your project and include as you include your stylesheet.

Don't add cdn link to your css.

Comment: Thank you! So to be clear in my muddled brain. Each page will contain links to the Bootstrap CDN and Java files and also a link to my CSS sheet. Does it matter in the head section if I put the CDN or CSS link first?

Comment: <head>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

     </head> and include the js just before the </body> tag

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. Are you going for page-speed?

If you want to optimize your website for page-speed I recommend combining both the CSS and JavaScript files in to single files (there are tools to [automate this process](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=bunddle%20and%20minify)). Also if you really want to optimize your website for page-speed you can apply both the combined CSS and JavaScript dynamically, by putting the following snippet just before the closing `body` tag so that the HTML can be rendered before executing the Javascript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function (sources) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = sources[i];
            head.appendChild(script);
        }
    })([
            '//domain.com/combined.js'
    ]);
</script>
```

Note that the JavaScript files are **not** loaded in synchronized order, but using a single combined script it doesn't matter.

For the sheets I use the following algorithm:

Determine if it is the first page view of the session:
If so, inline the combined CSS in the `head` tag:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style><? echo file_get_contens('./path_to_combined_style.css'); ?></style>
    </head>
</html>
```

If not, just include the CSS link in the `head` tag:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//domain.com/path-to-combined-style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Then you can force to cache to CSS style on the first load by executing a `XMLHttpRequest`, for simplicity I use `jQuery` here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var href = "//domain.com/path-to-combined-style.css";

    $link = $("link[href='" + href + "']");

    if ($link.size() === 0) {
        $.get(href);
    }

});
```

You can put this in the combined JavaScript.

Note that you won't be able to use the speed advantage of the CDN. To solve this you could publish your combined resources to your own CDN. You will loose the possibility that the user has already cached bootstrap though.

Ofcourse this whole process requires some knowledge and experience, so you might want to consider using a tool such as [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which does a pretty good job optimizing your website.